# OAuthException while posting action

Tags: action, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to post an action using the following javascript code:

```
FB.api('/me/spacemaze:fly_through',
'post',
{maze: 'http://www.gethugames.in/html5spacemaze/', lid: state.currentLevel, score: 1001},
function(resp) {
    if(!resp || resp.error) {
        console.log('err occured');
        console.log(resp.error);
    } else {
        console.log('successfull action');
        console.log(resp);
    }
});
```

But the request fails and get the following error:

```
code: 1
message: "An unknown error has occurred."
type: "OAuthException"
```

in Open Graph Dashboard, `fly_through` is defined as an action with 2 custom properties `lid` and `score` of `float` type. `Maze` is an Object and I havent created any aggregations.

What is wrong with my code?

**EDIT 1:**

I got an access token, verified it to be valid in access token debugger, but Issues field says unknown. Not sure if that is a problem.

Then in Graph API Explorer, I posted a query with following fields

```
URL: me/spacemaze:fly_through
maze: http://www.gethugames.in/html5spacemaze
lid: 5
score: 10.1
```

but getting the same error:

```
"error": {
"message": "An unknown error has occurred.", 
"type": "OAuthException", 
"code": 1
}
```

PS: I got permissions for `publish_stream` and `read_stream` under extended permissions. Isnt it suffice?

Comment: Are you testing this with a user that is a developer/tester of your app (or are your actions approved already)? Do you probably have the setting “Requires App Token to Publish” enabled for this action?

Comment: I am using a profile which is the admin of the app. `Requires App Token to Publish` for the action is set to NO. Not having any aggregation is a problem? Probably a stupid question, I still dont understand the open graph clearly...